# Generating SHA-0

Tags: sha

Unfortunately, I need to generate some SHA-0 hashes, I was using BouncyCastle and there's nothing in there to generating them.

I know it's weak and not secure, but regardless, I have to be able to use it.

I'm trying to avoid writing a method that does SHA-0 from scratch, and even that algorithm is hard to find on Google, since every SHA-0 article is about the collisions and weaknesses.

Does anyone know any tools I can use which still supports the SHA-0 method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SHA-0 is supported in [sphlib](http://www.saphir2.com/sphlib/); that library contains implementations of SHA-0 in both C and Java. The C code also comes with an appropriate command-line tool.

Repurposing a SHA-1 implementation into a SHA-0 implementation is not hard; the two functions differ only by an additional rotation in the "word expansion" step.